# Как склеить два обьекта в новый обьект, сохраняя выборочные значения

Tags: javascript

Друзья, вопрос немного скользкий, прошу тех кто может помочь внимательно прочитать.

У меня есть обьект **appTree: {}** со следующим содержимым:

```
appTree: {
        analytics: {
            title: 'Аналитика',
            icon: 'chart-pie',
            path: '/analytics/',
            subsections: []
        },
        employees: {
            title: 'Сотрудники',
            icon: 'user-secret',
            path: '/employees/',
            subsections: [
            {
                title: 'Сотрудники',
                path: 'agents/',
                access: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Аналитика',
                path: 'analytics/',
                access: false
            }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Данный обьект является шаблоном и единственным источником правды так сказать.

Данный обьект копируется в другой обьект, и затем хранится в базе данных. В интерфейсе с ним только одна работа - менять значения в массиве subsections в каждом из элементов поле access (true/false)

При получение обьекта из БД, я хочу получить новый обьект, который будет сначала создан на основание шаблона appTree, а затем внесет только сохраненные из бд значения по каждому из элементов в массиве subsections именно свойства access.! Тоесть порядок при прохождение по массиву и по обьекту важен, так как я ориентируюсь только по индексах.

Проблема заключается в том, что шаблон может быть изменен со временем. И я хочу что бы все обьекты которые хранятся в бд получили новую структуру шаблона, но перенесли значения access ориентируясь по индексах в массиве только те, которые у них есть.

Вот суть вопроса на примере кода:

Как я уже говорил есть шаблон, о представлен выше. На его основание сделали полую копию, но например поменяли значения в некоторых элементах вложенного свойства subsections (я изменил значение в **employees.susections[0].access**) и сохранили в бд.

```
appTree: {
        analytics: {
            title: 'Аналитика',
            icon: 'chart-pie',
            path: '/analytics/',
            subsections: []
        },
        employees: {
            title: 'Сотрудники',
            icon: 'user-secret',
            path: '/employees/',
            subsections: [
            {
                title: 'Сотрудники',
                path: 'agents/',
                access: TRUE
            },
            {
                title: 'Аналитика',
                path: 'analytics/',
                access: false
            }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Затем прошло время, в самом шаблоне приложения поменяли структуру, например изменили названия в свойствах title, поменяли path, добавили какие то новые элементы в subsections (но сохранили порядок элементов).

Я хочу получить новый обьект, который скопирует полностью шаблон appTree, но внесет ориентируясь на элементы массива subsections вложенного свойства access - true и false которые он хранил все время в бд. Больше ничего перетягивать в новый обьект со старого который был в бд мне ненадо, только значения по каждому из элементов access массива subsections

Comment: Ну, во-первых: причём здесь react, а во-вторых: в чём проблема-то? Сравнить два объекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const SAMPLE = {
  appTree: {
    analytics: {
      title: 'Аналитика',
      icon: 'chart-pie',
      path: '/analytics/',
      subsections: []
    },
    employees: {
      title: 'Сотрудники',
      icon: 'user-secret',
      path: '/employees/',
      subsections: [{
        title: 'Сотрудники',
        path: 'agents/',
        access: false
      }, {
        title: 'Аналитика',
        path: 'analytics/',
        access: false
      }]
    }
  }
};

const DATA_FROM_DB = {
  appTree: {
    analytics: {
      title: 'Аналитика',
      icon: 'chart-pie',
      path: '/analytics/',
      subsections: []
    },
    employees: {
      title: 'Сотрудники',
      icon: 'user-secret',
      path: '/employees/',
      subsections: [{
        title: 'Сотрудники',
        path: 'agents/',
        access: 'ИЗМЕНЕННОЕ ПОЛЕ'
      }, {
        title: 'Аналитика',
        path: 'analytics/',
        access: 'ПОДТВЕРЖДАЮЩЕЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ ПОЛЕ'
      }]
    }
  }
};

// Получаем массив `access`-ов данных из БД.
const ACCESSES = DATA_FROM_DB
  .appTree
  .employees
  .subsections
  .map(function(item, index) {
    return item.access;
  });

// Создаём копию объекта по шаблону. Deep clone.
const objCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SAMPLE));

// Изменяем в копии объекта `access`-ы.
// При условии, что количество этих `access`-ов
// такое же как и в БД,
// т.к. новое значение задаётся по индексу.
objCopy
  .appTree
  .employees
  .subsections
  .forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.access = ACCESSES[index];
  });

console.log(SAMPLE);
console.log(objCopy);
```